# How to update Document with mongoose

Tags: mongoose

```
var id = req.params.id;
var updatedDevice = req.body;

Device.update({ _id: id}, updatedDevice, function(err, device) {

    if (!err) {

        return res.send(device);

    } else {

        return console.log(err);

    }   

});
```

this one break with "Mod on _id not allowed"

> ```
> User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, user) {
>
>           user.activated = req.body.activated;
>           user.role = req.body.role;
>           user.save(function(err, user) {
>
>               if (!err) {
>
>                   return res.send(user);
>
>               } else {
>
>                   return console.log(err);
>
>               }   
>
>           });
>
> });
> ```

In this one i can't add the complete object like this:

```
//user.activated = req.body.activated;
//user.role = req.body.role;
user = req.body;
user.save(function(err, user) {...
```

there will be an save error :(

can you show me the best way please :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove the `_id` property from your update object:

```
var updatedDevice = req.body;
delete req.body._id;
```